# CURRENT-OFFSET For All Partition in a Topic In Confluent Kafka Returning -1001

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python, confluent-cloud

I am trying to calculate the Lag for a Consumer Group hosted in Confluent Kafka using the below Python Code

```
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, NewTopic
from confluent_kafka import KafkaException, KafkaError, Consumer
from confluent_kafka import TopicPartition

import json

# Set up the configuration for the Confluent Cluster
conf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'pkc-43332.us-west1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092',
        'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
        'sasl.mechanism': 'PLAIN',
        'sasl.username': '<user-name>',
        'sasl.password': '<pswd>'}

# Create the AdminClient using the configuration
admin_client = AdminClient(conf)

# Get the consumer group description
group_metadata = admin_client.list_groups()

# Check if the consumer group is active
group_name = 'connect-consumer-group'
if group_name not in [group.id for group in group_metadata]:
    print(f"No consumer group with name {group_name} found.")
    exit()

# Get the consumer group details
group_info = admin_client.describe_consumer_groups([group_name])
group_info = group_info[group_name].result()

# Get the topic partitions for the consumer group
topic_partitions = {}
for member in group_info.members:
    for tp in member.assignment.topic_partitions:
        topic_partitions[tp.topic] = topic_partitions.get(tp.topic, []) + [tp.partition]

# Create a Consumer object
consumer_conf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'pkc-43332.us-west1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092',
                 'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
                 'sasl.mechanism': 'PLAIN',
                 'sasl.username': '<user-name>',
                 'sasl.password': '<pswd>',
                 'group.id': group_name,
                 'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'}
consumer = Consumer(consumer_conf)

# Calculate lag for each topic partition
for topic, partitions in topic_partitions.items():
    for partition in partitions:
        tp = TopicPartition(topic, partition)
        current_offset = consumer.position([tp])[0].offset
        end_offset = consumer.get_watermark_offsets(tp)[1]

        # Calculate lag
        lag = end_offset - current_offset
        print(f"Lag for {topic}-partition-{partition}: {lag}, end offset is {end_offset}, current offset is {current_offset}")
```

In this the current-offset is always -1001 for all the partitions, where as the end-offset is correctly fetched from Confluent.
When I run the below command in shell, it returns the exact numbers for current and the end offset,

```
kafka-consumer-groups 
--bootstrap-server pkc-43332.us-west1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092 
--command-config /home/dbuser/client-config.properties 
--describe --group connect-consumer-group 
--timeout 10000
```

What can we do differently in Python(passing any additional parameters, adding/updating configurations etc) to get the exact current-offset as the command executed in command line?

Comment: Why not use existing tooling like Burrow or Kafka Exporter to get lag?

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer for your inputs! We do have limitations in using these tools against Confluent Prod environment. Hence, using the above methods

Comment: Confluent Cloud, you mean? Not that I know of. You may need to do some work to configure authentication. E.g. Burrow doesn't currently work with SASL_SSL , when I looked a few months ago